# JSONSchema for "array of objects, they can have any keys, but they all have to have the same keys"

Tags: validation, jsonschema

Is there a way to specify in a JSON schema that you want an array of objects, you don't care what keys the objects have, as long as they all have the same ones.

Basically, I want a schema that constrains you to describe a valid 2D table of data.

So this would be valid:

```
[
  {"foo": "a", "bar": "b"},
  {"foo": "c", "bar": "d"}
]
```

But this would not:

```
[
  {"foo": "a", "bar": "b"},
  {"baz": "c", "bar": "d"}
]
```

... because the two objects in the array don't share the same keys.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't do this with the standard JSON Schema specification.